# create geoTiff gdal from np array

Tags: python-3.x, image, export, gdal

I have a numpy array which has the shape is (7703,7703,9)

I want to export this array to 7700 rows x 7703 columns with 9 separated bands geoTiff image using gdal.

```
def CreateGeoTiff(outRaster, data, geo_transform, projection):
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    rows, cols, no_bands = data.shape
    DataSet = driver.Create(outRaster, cols, rows, no_bands, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    DataSet.SetGeoTransform(geo_transform)
    DataSet.SetProjection(projection)
    for i, image in enumerate(data, 1):
        DataSet.GetRasterBand(i).WriteArray( image )
    DataSet = None
```

but it returns error:

Segmentation fault (core dump)

Can you help me fix this error or how to export multi-band image using gdal.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that your loop expects another structure of your data.

From the line `rows, cols, no_bands = data.shape` it seems like your data has the shape where channels are last [rows, cols, channels].

Now when you loop I guess that you actually expect to be looping over each channel, but you are actually looping over each row.

In order to loop over each channel you should restructure your data to [channels, rows, cols]. This can be done with the following

`data = np.moveaxis(data, -1, 0)`

Hence you can rewrite your function as the following:

```
def CreateGeoTiff(outRaster, data, geo_transform, projection):
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    rows, cols, no_bands = data.shape
    DataSet = driver.Create(outRaster, cols, rows, no_bands, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    DataSet.SetGeoTransform(geo_transform)
    DataSet.SetProjection(projection)

    data = np.moveaxis(data, -1, 0)

    for i, image in enumerate(data, 1):
        DataSet.GetRasterBand(i).WriteArray(image)
    DataSet = None
```